# Evaluate Json - nested JSON path is provided as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eval

I have a string that carries the path of a nested JSON object:

```
var path = 'p_Data[0]["BusinessUnit"][0]["BusinessUnit"]'
```

How to evaluate the JSON in that path? Right now I use

```
eval(path)
```

I know using eval is not good. How to do this without using eval?

Comment: *eval* is only *evil* when it is used unnecessarily as it is slower than other forms of indexing. Given the format of the selector eval seems a reasonable solution. I would actually replace your pathing system if possible instead, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: What's the difference to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269046/how-to-replace-eval-to-update-value-in-json-when-json-path-is-provided-as-string)? Also, as I commented on another question of yours, there is no such thing a "JSON path" and your question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling I dont wana use eval()

Comment: @SreekeshOkky: You said the same in the previous question: *"how to replace this use of eval"*. So what is the *difference*? If there is none, please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) which extends the global object JSON with the method "search". Using this method you can search your JSON structure with XPath expressions, something like this:

```
JSON.search( data, '//p_Data[0]/BusinessUnit[0]/BusinessUnit' );
```

Since there is no example JSON structure, the suggestion above might work. If you post example of your structure, I can provide a JSFiddle version of my suggestion.

To get an idea of how XPath works, check out this XPath Evaluator tool:
http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator